# RX operator to scan with prior value, with signal deriving from value itself

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Say you have a source observable of type `IObservable<uint>`. I'm looking for a transformation function

```
IObservable<uint> Countdown(IObservable<uint> source)
{
  // how? Something like ...
  return source.Select(value => ProduceInnerObservable(value)).Switch()
}
```

that transforms `source` as follows:

- When `source` produces a value, the resulting observable should immediately publish the same value
- Say the last element published was `N`. In the absence of any new elements from `source`, the result observable should publish the value `N-1` after `N` ticks; then `N-2` after `N-1` ticks; and so on, until 0 is published
- When `source` publishes a new value, this timer-like behaviour is reset based on the new value

Example inputs/outputs:

| Tick time | Source observable | Result observable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 10 |  | 9 |
| 19 |  | 8 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 23 |  | 1 |
| 24 |  | 0 |
| 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 |  | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

What's the most elegant way to implement this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of "ticks" in your specific situation. Also try to include a [mcve]. And explain what should happen if the integer source reaches zero.

Comment: Also add information what should happen, when a new integer is produces in the original source, but the "tick" isn't generated yet.

Comment: @Progman I think your 2nd comment is covered by "When source publishes a new value, this timer-like behaviour is reset based on the new value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "ticks" are in tenths of a second - probably this will suit your needs:

```
static void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<int>();

    Countdown(subject).TimeInterval().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    subject.OnNext(10);

    Thread.Sleep(4000);

    subject.OnNext(2);

    Thread.Sleep(4000);

    subject.OnNext(1);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

static IObservable<int> Countdown(IObservable<int> source)
{
    return source.Select(value => Observable.Generate(
        initialState: value-1,
        condition: i => i >= 0,
        iterate: i => i-1,
        resultSelector: i => i,
        timeSelector: _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(value*100)
        ).StartWith(value)).Switch();
}
```